# Send intentionally invalid HTTP response with Express

Tags: javascript, http, express

I'm building a few tests for a web app and I'd like to test the ability of the client to gracefully handle invalid HTTP responses. How do you suggest mangling a response such that it's not longer valid? I tried the following but Express evidently fixed the `Content-Length` afterwards:

```
app.get('/broken/', function(req, res) {
    console.log('request received for ' + req.path);
    res.set('Content-Length', 0).send('more than zero');
});
```

**EDIT:** To note, I'm not necessarily in control of the incoming requests. In the past some of them have been invalid.

Comment: I'm not sure whether it makes sense to even handle invalid responses in the client. Either the response is valid or the client times out waiting for one

Comment: To me, this sounds like a job for `curl` or `netcat`.

Comment: You probably need to move away from a framework that has code around it to ensure valid responses where you can just send whatever you want.

Comment: @miparnisari: Edited to explain.

Comment: @JamesTaylor: I can indeed accomplish that with curl but that doesn't really fit into the existing unit test framework. I was hoping there would be a pure JS solution.

Comment: You could create a plain TCP server in node.js and then parse the incoming request and send your own response exactly as you want - essentially making your own simple little http server where you control everything.

Comment: @jfriend00 I could, but Express handles all the other cases very nicely and I would like to have the one web server, allowing it to handle state. For instance, maybe only every hundredth response is invalid.

Comment: If you use an existing server or framework, it almost certainly handles all the HTTP connection management, and will prevent invalid responses. You have to bypass the normal server and provide your own if you want that level of control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the right answer (even if you can work around it) is to *not* use a HTTP client for this. Any HTTP client would make an effort to prevent you from making invalid HTTP calls. The correct answer therefore is to make an intentionally non-conforming HTTP client, which implies you need to dive down to writing tcp sockets. Even if this means that this doesn't fully fit in your testing framework, I presume that you only need this for one test.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, `Express` resets `Content-Length` inside [response.send](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/response.js#L168-L178) method.

```
if (chunk !== undefined) {
  len = chunk.length;
  this.set('Content-Length', len);
}
```

Basically, `send` does nothing more than setting a bunch of headers and delegating the rest of work to [http.ServerResponse.end](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_end_data_encoding_callback).

In order to bypass this behaviour, you could use `end` method directly.

```
app.get('/broken/', function(req, res) {
  res.set('Content-Length', 0)
     .set('Content-Type', type);
     .end('more than zero');
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that actually accomplishes creating an invalid HTTP response. Unfortunately it seems that most clients just read the amount as specified by the content length and then continue happily, not throwing the hoped-for error.